# Cannot apply "Visible" method from a global class to multiple winforms in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, error-handling, visible

I need your help with something I am dealing with. I am new to c# and I am creating a winforms application with multiple forms in it. There's a piece of code that needs to be present on all forms but since I don't want to just copy and paste it in every form, I created a class that stores that code and then I only want to call that class.

My global code that needs to be repeated is as follows,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Delfoi_Tourist_Guide
{
    public class Login_User
    {
        public void CheckStatus()
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do your want to disconnect?;", "Disconnect", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Welcome form1 = new Welcome();
                form1.Show();
                this.Visible = false;
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Συνεχίστε την περιήγηση σας!!!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am also providing you a portion of code from another form in which I am applying my global code

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            Login_User loginUser = new Login_User();
            loginUser.CheckStatus();
        }
```

My problem is that I can't transfer the "Visible" method from my global class to the other classes. I suppose this happens because my global class isn't attached to a winform. It's just a piece of code that's been used globally. What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem occurs because the keyword "this" applies as property to the form, not the class. In your case you have to pass an instance of the form as parameter in your CheckStatus method. But since you want this to apply in all of your forms, you have to type the word "Form". Below I am providing you the answer,

**Your Global Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Delfoi_Tourist_Guide
{
    public static class Login_User
    {
        public static void CheckStatus(Form currentForm)
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do your want to disconnect?;", "Disconnect", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Welcome form1 = new Welcome();
                form1.Show();
                currentForm.Visible = false;
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Συνεχίστε την περιήγηση σας!!!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then you have to apply your global code to your desired forms, as follows.
Please note that you have to set the whole class as static in order for it, to work.

**Apply Global Code To Forms**

```
        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            Login_User.CheckStatus(this);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

``````
public  static void CheckStatus(System.Windows.Form currentForm)
 {
                .....
                currentForm.Visible = false;
                `````
 }
``````

and call it

```
   .....
 Login_User.CheckStatus(this);
   .....
```